# Why does my openMP 2.0 critical directive not flush?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am currently attempting to parallelize a maximum value search using openMP 2.0 and Visual Studio 2012. I feel like this problem is so simple, it could be used as a textbook example. However, I run into a race condition I do not understand.

The code passage in question is:

```
double globalMaxVal = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++)
{
    {/* ... */} // In this section I determine maxVal
    // Besides reading out values from two std::vector via the [] operator, I do not access or manipulate any global variables.

    #pragma omp flush(globalMaxVal) // IF I COMMENT OUT THIS LINE I RUN INTO A RACE CONDITION
    #pragma omp critical
    if(maxVal > globalMaxVal)
    {
        globalMaxVal = maxVal;
    }
}
```

I do not grasp why it is necessary to flush globalMaxVal. The openMP 2.0 documentation states: "A flush directive without a variable-list is implied for the following directives: [...] At entry to and exit from critical [...]" Yet, I get results diverging from the non-parallelized implementation, if I leave out the flush directive.

I realize that above's code might not be the prettiest or most efficient way to solve my problem, but at the moment I want to understand, why I am seeing this race condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Below I've now added a minimal, complete and verifiable example below requiring only openMP and the standard library. I've been able to reproduce the problem described above with this code.

For me some runs yield a globalMaxVal != 99, if I omit the flush directive. With the directive, it works just fine.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#include <Windows.h>

#include <omp.h>


int main()
{
    // Repeat parallelized code 20 times
    for(int r = 0; r < 20; r++)
    {
        int globalMaxVal = 0;

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int maxVal = i;

            // Some dummy calculations to use computation time
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 generator(rd());
            std::uniform_real_distribution<double> particleDistribution(-1.0, 1.0);

            for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
                particleDistribution(generator);

            // The actual code bit again
            #pragma omp flush(globalMaxVal) // IF I COMMENT OUT THIS LINE I RUN INTO A RACE CONDITION
            #pragma omp critical
            if(maxVal > globalMaxVal)
            {
                globalMaxVal = maxVal;
            }
        }

        // Report outcome - expected to be 99
        std::cout << "Run: " << r << ", globalMaxVal: " << globalMaxVal << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2:

After further testing, we've found that compiling the code in Visual Studio without optimization (/Od) or in Linux gives correct results, whereas the bugs surface in Visual Studio 2012 (Microsoft C/C++ compiler version 17.00.61030) with activated optimization (/O2).

Comment: If your description is accurate, I'd say it's a bug in the implementation. It would be much better if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've added a minimal, complete and verifiable example to the original question above.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code gives me the correct answer with and without the `flush` directive (as expected)

Comment: Hi Gilles! Can you tell me how you are compiling the code?

We've found that compiling it in Visual Studio without optimization (/Od) or in Linux gives correct results, whereas the bugs surface in Visual Studio 2012 with activated optimization (/O2). (I've also now added this information now to the main post.)

Comment: It should work, I can't reproduce it even with VS Express 2012, and I would be very careful with an implementation that messes this up. Also a shame that VS doesn't support reduction(max), which is what you would usually use in that case.

Comment: @Zulan Are you sure you enabled Open MP support in the language setting tab? I can reproduce the error when using VS2012 with OpenMP enabled and optimization enabled (other than /Od). That might actually be a bug! It works fine on linux though (icc and g++)